# Laravel 8 relationship of three models which belongs to Parent model

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Hello everyone I'm currently working on a laravel project where I have a parent table that has the id's of three tables referenced to it. These table migrations also have their models respectively. Here are the table migrations files respectively:

create_products_table.php

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product_id', 10);
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('images');
            $table->string('product_description');
            $table->bigInteger('size_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('product_quantity');
            $table->string('old_price');
            $table->string('discount');
            $table->string('product_price');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('gender_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('sizes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')->on('genders')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

create_genders_table.php

```
        Schema::create('genders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('gender_class');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

create_categories_table.php

```
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('cat_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

create_sizes_table.php

```
        Schema::create('sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('sizes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Also this is how I defined the relationships on their models respectively

Product.php

```
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    
    public function gender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gender::class);
    }
    
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }
```

Category.php

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Gender.php

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Size.php

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

I'm actually a laravel beginner and I studied eloquent model relationships at laravel.com so what I did was just based on my understanding of one to many relationships. When I check all my request with dd($request), category_id, gender_id, size_id all show null and I believe it's because I didn't define the relationship properly. Now this is where I seriously need your assistance.

So please my experienced developers I seriously need your help I'll really be grateful if I get your replies today. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at eager loading, specifically where it references “with” https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

```
=>Everything is right, just make changes in the products migration add this code.

$table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

=>and migrate table
```

Comment: I just did it but they still return null

Comment: I just did it but they still return null

Comment: you can pass foreign key and local key as 2nd and 3rd arguement in hasMany function and pass foreign key and owner key as 2nd and 3rd arguement in belongsTo function

Comment: public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: public function gender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gender::class,'gender_id','id');
    }

Comment: public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class,'size_id','id');
    }